# Setting camera position for multiple moving objects in a scene in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have two objects in my scene - a line and a sphere. Both of these need to be re-rendered in every iteration of requestAnimationFrame.

I have both of these individually working, however, when I use the sphere code with my line's init function (which has the camera positioning suitable for displaying the line), the sphere appears too big and the lighting doesn't cover the entire sphere. Basically, the sphere doesn't do well with the line's camera setting.

To get the sphere and line to work together as a scene using the line's camera settings, I had to change the sphere's size to much smaller and change the lighting. How can rendering multiple objects be achieved in a better way, without having to hack the properties of all other objects to fit the camera settings of one of the objects?

[Individual code for line](https://jsfiddle.net/zppa3bav/3/#&togetherjs=91TQsMfTsx)

[Individual code for sphere](https://jsfiddle.net/7oucpa8o/#&togetherjs=43lUFjx1pD)

[Line and sphere working together](https://jsfiddle.net/uc97auey/5/)
Notice how, in this version, the size of the sphere is only 0.8 to have it working together.

```
sphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.8,31,31), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            color: 'yellow',
        }));
```

Comment: Why are you using individual cameras for each object? Would it not be better to have one single scene camera (and some scene lighting) and then configure all for this camera?

Comment: @Wilt but, say if I configure the sphere for the settings of line, it's not very intuitive as to what the radius of sphere, and the lighting should be. How do I find these ? By trial and error?

Comment: Yes, I guess so, or by looking at examples. Or by using similar materials for example `LineBasicMaterial` and `MeshBasicMaterial`?